# I'm seeking assistance in configuring the WAL rotation to address an issue with memory exhausted in TimescaleDB

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I am utilizing the official single-node Helm chart for TimescaleDB 1.7.0 in my operations. We recently implemented a data pipeline involving a substantial influx of write operations per second. Unfortunately, after running the pipeline for two and a half days, I encountered a problem whereby my 12 GB Write-Ahead Log (WAL) memory became depleted. To resolve this issue, I need assistance with configuring the WAL rotation. Despite examining the values.yml file, I could not locate the relevant configuration option.

Answer (score 0):

can you please update your Timescaledb version? it's on [2.11](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/releases) and 1.7 was around 3 years ago. It will be very hard to find help and even debug and understand using a very old version.